# Where should I use nsrunloop?

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsrunloop

I studied something about run loop. That It is event processing loop. The RunLoop is what keeps your app running until it should quit. It handles events, etc. And also it makes our thread busy when it has work otherwise make it sleep.

But **I can't understand that where should I use `NSRunloop` in real time in my app?** Can any one give good idea?

Comment: You probably shouldn't look for excuses to use a brand new shiny tool you just got...

Comment: Theoretically I read lot. I just want to know that can you give any links?

Comment: You're asking the wrong question and probably designing your apps from the wrong perspective.  The right question (that you should ask yourself, not necessarily SO) is "I'm trying to do X.  What's the best tool for accomplishing X?"  Instead, you're asking "I've got a new tool X.  What can I put in my app as an excuse to use X?"

Comment: Thank you @Michal Ciuba just now I have open up the same link...